# how to get ajax post request data in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

I Want To Get Sent Data From Ajax in PHP
This My Javascript Code:

```
var formdata = "Hello"
$.ajax({
url: "test.php",
method: "POST",
data: formdata,
async: false,
```

So How Can I Get This Data in PHP?

Comment: You get it the same way you get any POST data. Ajax is not anything special.

Comment: You can either supply key-value pairs to the `data` property or use `jQuery("#yourform").serialize()` to send everything in a form. The easiest way to confirm your AJAX call is then working is to do a simple `print_r($_POST)` or `print_r($_REQUEST)` in the ajax endpoint. You can view the output by navigating to the Network panel of your dev tools, clicking into the ajax call and looking in the `Response` tab. You should then see the list of the values that were posted - if you dont see anything show up, something is wrong in your ajax call. You're pretty much there with the call itself though.

Comment: Aside from the above, remove `async: false`. It's terrible practice and should not be used.

Comment: ajax sends information well and asp.net receives information. But I want to do this in php. So I used "print_r ($ _POST)" but the result was: Array()